# laravel voyager - Error when updating background image in admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, voyager

I used laravel 5.4 and voyager 1.1, i updated the background image of admin page in Setting Menu. It shows an error. 
This error is still an issue ? or something i'd missed in my installation or configuration?

some features is working fined!

```
(1/1) NotReadableException
Unable to find file ().
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look in the directory the image is supposed to be uploaded to. If it's not there - perhaps its a permissions problem.

Comment: I think it's not a permission problem because i logged in in admin role

Comment: I mean folder permissions on your server. You need to make sure PHP has permissions to write files.

Comment: I already change the directory permission but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it.

***The problem:***

> PHP 8.1.8, Laravel 9.22.0 in Laragon
>
> Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
> Unable to find file ().

***The solution:***

Add this entry in your `php.ini`:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "YOUR_TEMP_DIR";
```

and reload the server.